# What is the physical difference between a 12V and 24 DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I've read the answers given for [this similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98902/what-is-the-difference-between-a-12v-and-24v-dc-motor) and they compare the performance of a 12V and 24V motor based on the power relationship (for the same mechanical load, twice as much current is drawn for the 12V as the 24V motor). However, I'm trying to understand what physically must change in a motor's design to enable it to operate efficiently at 24V versus 12V or vice versa?

Comment: More turns per coil of thinner wire.

Comment: If you take the 12V motor and rewind it with twice the turns of wire (thinner wire, i.e. half the area), you now have a 24V motor.